# Code to create and use volume slider in iphone app development using xcode

Tags: iphone, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller, xcode4.5, avplayer

I am creating a radio streaming app in iphone using xcode 4.2.
i have used Mpmovieplayercontroller to implement streaming from streaming URL with play and pause as seperate buttons.
i want code to implement volume slider, play and pause using single button( Converting between play to pause and pause to play). Is there any other framework can be used to accomplish the task?
please help me so that i can complete my task very easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you implement Mpmovieplayercontroller then volume slider is automatically in

controller. & also a button of pause/resume.